# It's factors all the way down!

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output, primes, fractal

This challenge is inspired by [this fantastic animated diagram](http://www.datapointed.net/visualizations/math/factorization/animated-diagrams/) (thanks to flawr for posting it in chat).

Given an input `n`, draw all of its prime factors as nested polygons of dots, as specified.

For example, given the number `357 = 17x7x3`, you arrange 3 dots in a triangle, 7 versions of those triangles in a heptagon, and 17 versions of those heptagons in a 17-gon. In short, nested polygons going from the largest prime factor on the outside to the smallest on the inside. For `357`, your answer should look a little like this (with or without color):

[image]

Every polygon of every prime `>= 3` should not be rotated around the diagram.

The only exception is the prime `2`, specifically for odd powers of `2`. As you can see in the example for `376 = 47x2x2x2` below, the `8`s rotate and are not single lines of `2`s, but are vertical stacks for `4`s in a square. Even powers of `2`, arranged in squares, do not need to be rotated in this way.

[image]

In fact, `448 = 7x2x2x2x2x2x2` has a diagram that looks like a heptagon of `64`s, and `64` is arranged into a square of squares of squares, but without rotation.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Two more examples are `440 = 11x5x2x2x2` and `432 = 3x3x3x2x2x2x2`. We see that `440` with an odd power of 2, has rotated `8`s, but `432` with an even power of `2` does not rotate its `16`s.

[image] [image]

And finally, here is a minimal example, `10 = 5x2`, without color that I mocked up with Python and its `turtle` module.

[image]

**The challenge**

- Given an input `n` where `1 <= n <= 10000`, output an image of its nested factor polygons.
- Rules are:

  - The image is made up of nested polygons of dots, from a polygon with (the largest prime factor) sides on the outside to the smallest prime factor on the inside.
  - For the factor 2, the powers of 2 should stack as a line, then a squares, then a line of squares, and so on. Even powers of 2 should not be rotated. Odd powers of 2 should be rotated around their respective polygons, and they should be stacked vertically before rotation.
- You may orient the image however you like (though I prefer up), but every nested polygon should be facing the same direction as any other polygon with the sole exception of odd powers of 2.
- You have two options for image size and dot size:

  - The image size is static and the dot size decreases as `n` increases (as in the animation).
  - The dot size is static and the image size grows as `n` increases.
- The first **three** layers of polygons should be distinguishable from neighboring polygons (i.e. not touching), but considering the size of the images at and around `n=10000`, it's okay if the layers after start to touch. I'd prefer it if they didn't, but it may be unavoidable to fit on an image that is uploadable to Stack Exchange.
- Color is optional.
- The shape of the dots is up to you. If squares are better for your language, use those.
- No bonuses, but I would like to see someone animate and color the diagrams like in the original post.

Thanks to Conor O'Brien, EasterlyIrk, Martin Ender, Kritixi Lithos, Mego, DJ McMayhem, and El'endia Starman for their help in writing this question.

This code golf, so shortest code wins. Good luck and good golfing!

Answer (score 10):

## Python 3.5, <s>331</s> <s>309</s> <s>308</s> <s>306</s> 304 bytes

It took quite a bit of messing with the spacing of the polygons (and the specification, too, to be honest) to get this answer to work, but I finally did it and hopefully other answers can start coming in.

**Edit:** -2 bytes thanks to FlipTack. -8 bytes from removing a section of code that I forgot to remove earlier. -12 bytes from golfing the last function. -1 byte from changing the circumference of the drawings from `size=2500` to `size=2e3`, which also allows the drawings to better fit on screens (`diameter ~= 795.77` down to `diameter ~= 636.62`). -2 bytes from fixing a bug. -2 bytes from restructuring how I build `a`.

Golfing suggestions welcome. Trinket for testing and images to follow shortly.

```python
from math import*
from turtle import*
ht();pu()
def g(n):
 i=1;a=[]
 while n%4<1:a+=4,;n//=4
 while n>1:
  i+=1
  while n%i<1:a+=i,;n//=i
 return f(a,2e3)
def f(a,s,x=0,y=0,t=0):
 if a:
  *c,b=a;s/=b
  for i in range(b):u=2*pi*i/b+t*(b<3)+pi/4*(b==4);f(c,s,x+s*sin(u),y+s*cos(u),u)
 else:goto(x,y);dot(4)
```

Here's `g(448)`, which now fits on my 1366x768 screen.

[image]

**Ungolfing**

```python
import math
import turtle

turtle.hideturtle()     # don't display the turtle itself)
turtle.penup()          # don't draw lines, just dots later on

def g(n):
    i = 1
    a = []
    while n % 4 == 0:   # get 4's into the list first,
        a = a + [4]     # so that the fractal will be easier to structure
        n = n // 4
    while n > 1:        # now get all of the other factors (including any stray 2's)
        i += 1
        while n % i == 0:
            a = a + [i]
            n = n // i
    return f(a, 2000)   # 2000 is the circumference of the circle
                        # on which we draw the polygons
def f(a, s, x=0, y=0, t=0):
    if a:
        c = a[-1]       # the size of the current outermost polygon
        b = a[:-1]      # the rest of the factors for recursion
        s = s/b         # the current circumference / the number of polygons at this layer
        for i in range(b):
            u = 2*math.pi*i/b   # angle around the circle
            if b == 2:          # if b == 2, add the previous angle to rotate the structure
                u += t
            if b == 4:          # if b == 4, add 45 degrees to keep the squares upright
                u += math.pi/4
            dx = s * math.sin(u)    # our coordinate changes for this polygon
            dy = s * math.cos(u)
            f(c, s, x+dx, y+dy, u)  # call the function again
                                    # on a new circle with new starting coordinates
    else:                   # when we run out of factors,
        turtle.goto(x,y)    # go to each coordinate
        turtle.dot(4)       # and draw a dot
```

Comment: is `n = n //= i` supposed to be `n//= i` ?

Comment: @Bobas_Pett Nah, you're looking at the ungolfing/explanation, and that's supposed to say `n = n // i`. I'll go fix it and add to the explanation while I'm at it.